# Dynamics CRM - How to handle an odata.nextlink response in .Net

Tags: c#, rest, odata, dynamics-crm

I have the following piece of code that retrieves transactions from a Dynamics CRM (querying with OData):

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Transaccion>> GetTransactions()
    {
        var tableName = Transaccion.CrmTableName;

        var request = new RestRequest($"/api/data/v8.0/{tableName}");
        request.AddHeader("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=500");
        var responseData = await client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<ODataResponse<List<Transaccion>>>(request);
        var transactions = responseData.Data.Value;

        while (responseData.Data.NextLink != null)
        {
            request = new RestRequest(responseData.Data.NextLink);
            request.AddHeader("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=500");
            responseData = await client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync<ODataResponse<List<Transaccion>>>(request);
            transactions.AddRange(responseData.Data.Value);
        }

        return transactions;
    }
```

once I execute the first "ExecuteGetTaskAsync", I get for my example and as expected a NextLink attribute that points to the next set of entities that I need to retrieve. However, when I try to perform the next RestRequest, I don't get a JSON as response, but a Html page corresponding to a redirect, where I can read the error message "".

It's weird, since the first call could be made correctly because the Restclient was correctly authenticated.

What's going on? How can I do paging with Dynamics CRM in .Net and use the NextLink?

Answer (score 2):

In my case URL in @odata.nextLink was with an error.

How it was:

```
http://[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/[entity]/(68e95f08-d372-e711-966b-defe0719ce9e)/[relation entity]?$select=ne_name
```

And that did not work, but this did:

```
http://[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/[entity](68e95f08-d372-e711-966b-defe0719ce9e)/[relation entity]?$select=ne_name
```

There is no "/" between [entity] and (*id*)

Answer (score 0):

The odada nextlink returns the full URL of the next request so you'll need to parse it to get only the /api/** portion.